# How to solve this first order PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$$ u_y+\frac{y}2u(x,y)=0$$

What method should I use to solve this since I don't really know where to begin.

Comment: Is that $\ast$ a convolution or simply multiplication?

Comment: It's a multiplication, I'll edit it to make it clear.

Comment: It's not really a PDE because there's no derivative with respect to $x$.  It's just a first-order ODE where the "constant" in the general solution can depend arbitrarily on $x$.

Answer (score 3):

$u$ and $y$ (and $x$) are separable so rearrange to $\frac{u_y}{u}=-\frac{y}{2}$

Then integrate with respect to $y$.

$$\log u+f(x)=-\frac{y^2}{4}$$

where $f(x)$ is a function of $x$ (only).

$$u=e^{-\frac{y^2}{4}-f(x)}$$

Some textbooks will then rearrange it as follows to present a 'neater' solution.

$$u=e^{-\frac{y^2}{4}}\cdot e^{-f(x)}$$

$$u=g(x)\cdot e^{-\frac{y^2}{4}}$$

where $g(x)=e^{-f(x)}$